# Ubuntu 14.04 Suddenly stopped detecting HDMI monitor (Integrated graphics)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I usually have my laptop connected to a second monitor via HDMI, and for the past few months that has never been an issue. I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15R with Intel i7 and no dedicated graphics.

Yesterday I disconnected my laptop and took it elsewhere, and since I returned I have been unable to get the second monitor to show. I have tried using a friends monitor, and that didn't work either. Just to be sure, I had them try my monitor and which for them work (same one I was having issues with) so I came to the conclusion that my computer is the issue.

I have taken the laptop away many many times before and it was always as easy as connecting it back up. I didn't do anything special on it this time, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make any progress? This started happening to me, 2017-05-14.  I suspect a failure of the motherboard or hdmi connector. I plugged in the laptop and HDMI was not recognized, and then several hours later the HDMI was suddenly found by xrandr and external display started working.